# How can I separate the number form a string in an id of a div an turn the string into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I want to get the last Id of a div and then convert it into a variable

```
<div class="margin_bot" id="itemRows2"> 
  <p id="rowNum1">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum2">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum3">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum4">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum5">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum6">...</p>
</div>
```

So I know you can get the last id in a div with:

```
$('#itemRows2').children().last().attr('id');
```

Which returns `"rowNum6"` so my question is how can I grab just the number `6` and put it into a var like `var row1Num` in Jquery?

Comment: this is shorter `var id = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='rowNum']").length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regex that matches numbers for this:

```js
let id = $('#itemRows2').children().last().attr('id');

let num = Number(id.match(/\d+/));

console.log(num)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemRows2"> 
  <p id="rowNum1">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum2">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum3">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum4">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum5">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum6">...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly and it's so elegant.

Comment: Thanks :-) It really is

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split()` like :

```js
var myId = $('#itemRows2').children().last().attr('id');
var myNumber = myId.split('rowNum')[1];

console.log(myNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin_bot" id="itemRows2">
  <p id="rowNum1">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum2">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum3">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum4">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum5">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum6">...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split the id by number

```js
let m = $('#itemRows2').children().last().attr('id').trim().split(/(\d+)/)[1]
console.log(m)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin_bot" id="itemRows2">
  <p id="rowNum1">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum2">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum3">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum4">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum5">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum6">...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var text = $('#itemRows2').children().last().attr('id');

console.log(text.match(/\d/g)[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin_bot" id="itemRows2">
  <p id="rowNum1">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum2">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum3">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum4">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum5">...</p>
  <p id="rowNum6">...</p>
</div>
```